# django-registration: ImproperlyConfigured: No module named backends.default

Tags: django, django-registration

I've run into a very odd problem with django-registration, and I'm sort of at a loss for how to proceed. On my local development machine running OS X 10.8.2, python 2.7.2 and virtualenv 1.8.2, I'm working with django-registration 0.8 and a hacked up version of django-email-usernames 1.0, (which was having some problems with django-registraiton 0.8). Everything works perfectly, and I get no errors.

On my dev server, if I try to login or register a new account, I get the following error:

ImproperlyConfigured

Error importing authentication backend *site-name*registration.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend: "No module named backends.default"

I believe the relevant code is:

```
from registration.backends.default import DefaultBackend

class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(DefaultBackend):
```

The only difference between the two environments is the OS and python version on the staging server, (Debian Squeeze and 1.66 respectively). I'm not sure how it's possible that the exact same package versions supporting the exact same codebase are experiencing totally different behaviors. I'd be grateful for any insight anyone can lend.

Just in case there is any useful information therein, here is the pythonpath on my remote machine:

```
['/usr/local/*virtualenv*/*site-name*', '/usr/local/*virtualenv-name*/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/*virtualenv*/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL']
```

Something else odd that I have noticed: from registration.backends.default import DefaultBackend works fine in the shell.

Comment: Maybe the `registraion` app isn't in your python.path? Just start `python` in your shell and type `import sys` then hit `sys.path`. Is the `regstration` app within one of this paths?

Comment: At present my python.path seems correct. I'll add it to the question in case there is some useful information.